# How do I know when user clicked Facebook like button?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I tried to implement the Like button along with some code fired on liking the page, but I'm unable to get it working.

When I like the page FIrebug shows this error:

```
Event.__inlineSubmit is not a function
```

and nothing happens (ie no alert / redirection / whatever) besides the page being liked by me. The code so far:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({ appId: '---MYAPPID---', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true });
        FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function (href, widget) {
            // track the click on the "Like" button here
            alert(href);
        });
    };
    (function () {
        var e = document.createElement('script');
        e.type = 'text/javascript';
        e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        e.async = true;
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    } ());
//-->
</script>

<div class="fb-like" data-send="false" data-layout="box_count" data-width="60" data-show-faces="false"></div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
function(response) {
    alert('You liked the URL: ' + response);
}
);
```

Comment: I'm getting an error: Event.__inlineSubmit is not a function - even when using this code

Comment: Tested your code, its working fine... may be error is somewhere else in your code.